# APS in sklearn ( invalid value encountered in true_divide)

Tags: python, scikit-learn

when i do following code:

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score,average_precision_score

y_true=np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
y_scores=np.array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

average_precision_score(y_true, y_scores)

# ERROR
/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_ranking.py:817: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
recall = tps / tps[-1]
```

if I change it to below:

```
average_precision_score(y_scores,y_true)
#output: 0.16666666666666666
```

I am not able to get what is going wrong here.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just found out that:

we can apply `average_precision_score` with two classes.

the obvious reason is, we need, TN, TF, FN, and FP.

I have applied `average_precision_score`, just with one class (`y_true`) which cause this error and problem.